# How to use location markers as buttons in Flutter?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am making a transport (asset) tracking app in flutter. And Displaying all their different assets in google maps using the google maps plugin. I wanted to show the information about the asset when the users click on the current location marker of the asset. In simpleton, I want to use the location marker as buttons. If there is any other way of achieving this pls share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be some code for adding markers like following just add `onTap`

```
markers.add(
            Marker(
              zIndex: 100,
                markerId: MarkerId(myList[i].code),
                position: LatLng(myList[i].latitude, myList[i].longitude),
                icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueRed)

                ),
                onTap: () {
                  //this is what you're looking for!
                  setState(() {
                    currCode=myList[i].code;
                    //call something here with myList[i].code or store in global constant for widget state

                  });

                }
            )
```